# Batching inserts with RxJava

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java

I need to load data (up to 22,000 records) from a JSon feed and store them on my android device (in SQLite).

Doing individual inserts is easy to implement but slow. Ideally I would like to batch up the objects to insert and pass a list of these objects to the db.

I can see how to do it imperatively but I would really like to do it with RxJava but not sure how.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) operator?

Comment: You can check how it could be done here: https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc#transactions

Comment: @SergiiPechenizkyi that looks great except there's no jdbc on Android:(

Comment: @Ziem that looks promising. Struggling to find any examples though in Java. What happens when it runs out of items but hasn't reached the buffer limit?

Comment: I posted answer with buffer example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) operator to accumulate objects.

Example:

```
Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            subscriber.onNext("a");
        }

        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
});

stringObservable
    .buffer(5)
    .subscribe(new Observer<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.i("rxjava", "onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.i("rxjava", "onError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<String> strings) {
            Log.i("rxjava", "onNext " + strings.size());

            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                for (String string: strings) {
                    //insert data here
                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
    });
```

Output:

> onNext 5
>
> onNext 4
>
> onCompleted

Since I'm RxJava beginner I can't tell if this is the most robust way to achieve your goals.

---

If you are looking for reactive SQLite you should have a look at [SQLBrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL transaction to insert your items in a single transaction.

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    //insert data here
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

edit 1:

Would something like this work?

```
myObservable.insertIntoDatabase(json)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(//called when the insert is complete);
```

edit 2:

Inserting NUM_ITEMS at a time using an SQL transaction.

```
myObservable.buffer(NUM_ITEMS).flatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<String> call(List<String> strings) {
                //insert items here using SQL transaction
                return Observable.just("Inserted items " + strings.size());
            }
        }).subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: I know that bit. Its the the RxJava part that calls it with a list I'm asking about.

Comment: @FinalFive if you are calling it from a background thread you don't need RxJava. If you are calling it from the Main thread you just need to use the schedulers to call it on a background thread

Comment: you are not addressing my question - how to batch up emitted items using RxJava.

Comment: @FinalFive looks like I didn't quite get the question. See if my edit helps.

Comment: where's the batching?

Comment: @FinalFive you can insert NUM_ITEMS at a time. The subscribe is called every time NUM_ITEMS are inserted. Is this what you are looking for?